# Remove hanging PS3 input via bluetooth to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, bluetooth

I am working on a remote controlled vehicle based project. I am using a PS3 bluetooth controller for this purpose & am facing the problem described below. Any help would be appreciated.

Basically, the motors are connected to the MEGA which is connected to a USB Host Shield. A bluetooth dongle is connected to the shield. This dongle & shield enable MEGA to communicate with PS3 wirelessly. I am using the [USB Host 2.0](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) library available for Arduino on GitHub.

My code to take input from the PS3 is as follows:

```
USB.Task();
if ( PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected )
{
    if ( PS3.getAnalogButton(UP) )
        Serial.println("UP");
    if ( PS3.getAnalogButton(DOWN) )
        Serial.println("DOWN");
    if ( PS3.getAnalogButton(LEFT) )
        Serial.println("LEFT");
    if ( PS3.getAnalogButton(RIGHT) )
        Serial.println("RIGHT");
}
```

This is the code inside loop(). If anyone is wondering why getAnalogButton is used instead of getButtonClick, the reason is to enable the vehicle to move ahead as long as UP is pressed & so on. This was an improvisation on our part.

As can be seen, the function prints UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT as long as they are pressed continuously. The problem is that it works perfect for a while. But then, it enters an infinite loop & stops taking input from the PS3.

Basically, the input is like

```
UP
UP
UP
UP
UP
UP
UP
.....
LEFT
LEFT
LEFT
// At this point it hangs without printing any further inputs.
```

Can someone help tackle this problem? It is essential for us to move the vehicle as long as the buttons are pressed & stop when button is released. Unfortunately, there is no feature to detect PRESSED or RELEASED state for PS3. Any help would mean a lot.

Also, we initially thought that the hang was because of overflowing the serial input. So, we removed all Serial messages & tested with LEDs. But, the same problem is still faced.

Comment: I think the most precise answer you can get is "Something is blocking your loop". If you want more help, you'll have to share more information. For instance, what else is there in your program? Which library are you using? Can you understand what is the function blocking everything (I mean, does the USB.task hang or the checks are failing?)? Moreover the title and the text are different: are you actually experiencing lag or it hangs?

Comment: Depending on how you are reading the serial data, there might be a read buffer that's getting full and not getting purged.  I had this when using SoftwareSerial on a recent project.  I don't have the code handy, and my Google-fu is failing me on finding the same solution, but I had to "redeclare" a SoftwareSerial buffer variable on each loop.  I'll try to remember to look this up after work tonight, because I know what I said isn't clear.

Comment: What other details would it take to answer the question??? @frarugi87 Let me know. I'll provide those straight away.

Comment: The same goes for you too @computercarguy

Comment: You need to figure out where it is hanging, if it is even doing so - a fairly likely possibility could be the BT connection dropping at which point your posted code would seemingly do nothing.

Comment: @SamagraSinghTomar quoting from my previous comment, " For instance, what else is there in your program? Which library are you using? Can you understand what is the function blocking everything (I mean, does the USB.task hang or the checks are failing?)? "

Comment: It hangs randomly after a certain amount of time. No further input is received unless the connection is reset. Although, the connection seems to be intact when it hangs.

Comment: I am unable to figure out the reason for the hang. For your reference, I am using the PS3BT library example from USB Host 2.0 library whose GitHub link is posted above. I don't think there is any other library availbale for this purpose. I'm a beginner at arduino. So, if you can help me find out the reason for the hang, I would show you my complete code for better understanding. @frarugi87

Comment: @SamagraSinghTomar try to add a println after the USB.task call and another inside the if. If it totally hangs, the other printlns will stop printing. If the USB connection drops but the task can exit, you will see the println inside the loop stop printing. In any case try also another BT adapter (I'm not sure whether the authors recommend a specific BT dongle)

Comment: Will do that & get back to the conversation...Thanks for your time @frarugi87.